# Create database View in PostgreSQL and change record values simultaneously

Tags: postgresql, view

To cut a long story short, is it possible to create a database view in postgres and at the same time change the record values for a specific column ?

```
CREATE VIEW ViewOfCoupons AS
SELECT *
FROM Coupons
WHERE title = 'Category_1' OR title = 'Category_2';
```

I want to rename the records contained in the view to have different title other than 'Category_1' or 'Category_2', lets say 'Category_3'. In fact, as I mention in the commect, 'Category_3' is a supercategory involving the other two. So I only want the rows having these values. Is this possible with CASE statement ?

Comment: Do you want to see only rows with those categories? Or all rows and only "rename" those two categories?

Comment: Yes, I want to see only rows with those two categories. In fact, 'Category_3' is a supercategory involving those two. I will edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW ViewOfCoupons AS
SELECT case title
         when 'Category_1' then 'Brand new category' 
         when 'Category_2' then 'The other category'
         else title
       end as title, 
       ... other columns ...
FROM Coupons
WHERE title in ('Category_1', 'Category_2');
```

Strictly speaking the `else title` is not necessary because the `WHERE` clause makes sure that no other values will appear in that column, but I add this nevertheless to be prepared for future changes, e.g. if someone changes the `where` clause but forgets to change the `case` as well.

Comment: I think that you don't need the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @redneb: well it was present in the original query. It's unclear to me if dpesios want's only rows with those values or all rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see your point and thank you. But I want to get all the rows of Coupons (projecting all the columns) where the category is 'Category_1' or 'Category_2' and change it in the view.

Comment: It's already there, the answer (... other columns ...). Thanks!